# add an array to the list without repeating

Tags: c#, arrays, list, collections

There is an array and a list of the same type. In a loop, I change the array and after each change I add it to the list (at the end of the cycle I want to get a list of all the arrays that resulted from the changes). But when listing all its elements are the same, they are the same as the last array added to the list. Why is this happening?

```
        byte[,] mat = new byte[3, 3];
        List<byte[,]> list = new List<byte[,]>();

        for (int m = 0; m < 9; ++m)
        {
            byte i = 0;
            byte j = 0;

            // Search for an empty cell (zero)
            bool flag = false;
            for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
                    if (mat[i, j] == 0)
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                if (flag) break;
            }

            // Adding a changed array to the list
            mat[i, j] = 1;
            list.Add(mat);

            // List all items in the list
            foreach (byte[,] a in list)
            {
                PrintMatrix(a);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Should `mat[i,j] = 1;` be right before your `flag = true;`? You are just always making the 0,0 position 1 since i and j are not changing outside your for loop.

Comment: Not an answer, but can I strongly suggest you not name a List `list`?  `mats`?  `listMats`?  `matList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mat` is one object. Inside the loop, you keep adding the same object, `mat`, to the `List`. When you are done, you have a `List` that consists of multiple pointers to the one object `mat`, which are identical.

Imagine a Post Office with mailboxes that are numbered. One of the boxes (e.g. 15) is your `mat` `Array` variable. So in our analogy `mat` is 15. Your `List` `list` is a piece of paper. Each time around the loop you put something different in the mailbox, then you write 15 on the bottom of the paper.

When you take your final paper and go to each mailbox to see what's in it, you just keep going to number 15 and seeing the same thing(s).

BTW, I think you have your print loop in the wrong location - it should be outside the `m` loop.

To fix it, you need to make a copy of `mat` to add to the `List`:

```
var mat = new byte[3, 3];
var list = new List<byte[,]>();

for (int m = 0; m < 9; ++m) {
    byte i, j = 0;

    // Search for an empty cell (zero)
    bool flag = false;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            if (mat[i, j] == 0) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        if (flag) break;
    }

    // Adding a changed array to the list
    mat[i, j] = 1;
    list.Add((byte[,])mat.Clone());

}

// List all items in the list
foreach (byte[,] a in list) {
    PrintMatrix(a);
}
```

Comment: What does this mean `$"flag == {flag}".Dump();` ?

Comment: Sorry, I use LINQPad for trial code and left in some debug stuff.